# Динамическая генерация столбцов в Grid wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Требуется во время исполнения программы генерировать дополнительные столбцы у Grid с заданным свойством. Количество столбцов и их данные получаются из БД. Лейблы делаются для группировки столбцов, объединенных какими-либо свойствами (столбцы - даты, лейблы над ними - месяца)
То, что имеется:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="GridLabels">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column1, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column2, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column3, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column4, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Background="#FF878080" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >Header 1</Label>
        <Label Background="#FFE08787" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >Header 2</Label>
    </Grid>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 1" Width="200" x:Name="Column1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 2" Width="200" x:Name="Column2"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 3" Width="200" x:Name="Column3"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 4" Width="200" x:Name="Column4"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Для грида с `Name=GridLabels` нужно во время исполнения генерировать столбцы со свойством `Width` по типу остальных(меняя `ElementName` соответственно)

Предполагаю, что как-то так:

```
ColumnDefinition c5 = new ColumnDefinition();
Binding b = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
    ElementName = "Column5"
};
/*...*/
GridLabels.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c5);
```

Comment: Вот вам, вроде хорошая инструкция того, что вы хотите - [тык](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, нет, мне нужно чтобы из кода C# добавлялась колонка со свойством width с биндингом, а не обычным. Вопрос как ЭТО сделать. А по Вашей ссылке - просто добавление колонок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
ColumnDefinition gridColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
Binding bindingColumn = new Binding
{
    ElementName = String.Format("Column{0}", 5),
    Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth")
};
gridColumn.SetBinding(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, bindingColumn);
GridLabels.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColumn);
```